# Android Wear: bluetooth vs wifi connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, wifi, wear-os

How to detect if Android wear switched the connection from bluetooth to wifi or vice versa? And is there a way to force it to connect via bluetooth?

Comment: Please do not down vote without specifying a reason so we can discuss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an Android framework, you can register a broadcast receiver to be notified when connectivity status changes. In general, when your watch is connected to a phone directly (which only happens via BT), wifi connection is dropped and when it is not connected, if your phone is wifi capable and if a wifi network is available, it gets connected to the cloud node. In that case, you cannot force it to connect through BT since, most likely, it is not possible (might be due to distance or many other reasons). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?